# MDX queries contain Where and Subqueries (From) which one should I use?

Tags: mdx

Please can anyone assist me with a question that I have regarding MDX that is generated automatically within SSRS.

The dataset contains parameters, it constructs the parameter within a Subquery (From...) but also duplicates it by adding it to the Where clause aswell.

Can anyone tell me what is the actual difference in having the parameter in the From or the where, does it need to be in both places, and can I/should I remove either from the Where clause in order to improve performance/reduce unecessary code?

Any help appreciated. Thanks